# What are quantum extremal surfaces from a mathematical viewpoint?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, general-relativity

It is said that they are surfaces which locally maximize area and bulk entanglement entropy. It would be great if I could receive some introductory material on it and some prerequisites to understand them. I have a reasonable background in differential and algebraic geometry and topology at the beginner grad level. Also, it would be helpful to know their relation to minimal surfaces in euclidean space/ maximal surfaces in lorentz minkowski space. Thanks in advance.